# Clear all items from the queue

Tags: python, queue

How can I clear a queue. For example I have datas in a queue, but for some reason I don't need the existing data, and  just want to clear the queue.

Is there any way? Will this work:

```
oldQueue = Queue.Queue()
```

Comment: If you read the documentation, it refers you to the Queue module's [latest source](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#Queue.Queue), and there you could see the that the internal representation of a FIFO queue is a `deque`. In the documentation for `deque` you'd notice it has a `clear()` method, which is what you want. You'd probably also want to wrap that call with a `q.mutex.acquire()` and `q.mutex.release()` as the rest of the code does around such operations to make it thread safe.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
q = Queue.Queue()
q.queue.clear()
```

**EDIT**
I omitted the issue of thread safety for clarity and brevity, but @Dan D is quite correct, the following is better.

```
q = Queue.Queue()
with q.mutex:
    q.queue.clear()
```

Comment: if you do `with q.mutex: q.queue.clear()`, this operation would be thread safe.

Comment: @DanD. please correct me if I'm wrong but this actually seems to be a **bad** idea to me. `.mutex` and `.queue` [seems to be undocumented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and if I'm not mistaken, using `q.mutex` would **dead-lock** if you do anything like even `q.get_nowait` inside its block.

Comment: @Jean-BernardJansen: It's not automatically threadsafe if you're screwing with its internals directly, and `q.queue.clear()` is screwing with the internals directly.

Comment: n611x007 and user2357112 are correct. I would exepect an underscore before undocumented/private members, misleading me in believing clear() was in the safe API. Clearing a queue looks like a bad idea anyway, better to read it and drop uneeded items.

Comment: Note, as stated below in V.E.O's answer, simply clearing is not enough since even though the queue will be empty, the corresponding tasks haven't been marked as done. This may cause your code to lock up.

Comment: I used the approach below as well,

with q.mutex:
         size = len(q.queue)
         q.queue.clear()
         q.unfinished_tasks -= size




that sorted the issue for the join() blocking

Comment: that sorted the issue for the join() blocking, also it is an order of 400 times better in terms of time

Comment: This solution is not effective if q.join is used. This doesn't reset the unfinished job's count so they can cause unexpected side effects. (ie not being able to join)

Answer (score 48):

You just can not clear the queue, because every put also add the unfinished_tasks member.
The join method depends on this value.
And all_tasks_done needs to be notified also.

```py
with q.mutex:
    q.queue.clear()
    q.all_tasks_done.notify_all()
    q.unfinished_tasks = 0
```

or in decent way, use get and task_done pair to safely clear the tasks.

```py
    while not q.empty():
        try:
            q.get(block=False)
        except Empty:
            continue
        q.task_done()
```

or just create a new Queue and delete old one.

Comment: Use caution with that method, too. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#queue-objects) note, "if empty() returns False it doesn’t guarantee that a subsequent call to get() will not block."

Comment: @Lack Yes, fix it by non-blocking get

Comment: the second way (the "decent" one) seems to be the safest and more elegant way, and uses only the documented, public API. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: It seems these would have slightly different behaviors on a concurrent put. The first will block the concurrent put, while the second will catch and remove the concurrent put on the next loop. Right?

Comment: The decent way has no guarantee that it will end at all. Not to mention the loop overhead. I'd stick with the first way.

Comment: @V.E.O you saved me a lot of headache. The accepted solution is not effective if the queue uses join(). The unfinished tasks count is not reset.

Answer (score 12):

This seems to do it pretty well for me. I welcome comments/additions in case I missed anything important.

```
class Queue(queue.Queue):
  '''
  A custom queue subclass that provides a :meth:`clear` method.
  '''

  def clear(self):
    '''
    Clears all items from the queue.
    '''

    with self.mutex:
      unfinished = self.unfinished_tasks - len(self.queue)
      if unfinished <= 0:
        if unfinished < 0:
          raise ValueError('task_done() called too many times')
        self.all_tasks_done.notify_all()
      self.unfinished_tasks = unfinished
      self.queue.clear()
      self.not_full.notify_all()
```

Comment: This seems to be the most efficient (call to `.clear()`) and correct (notifications that include currently processed items) way to do that.

Comment: Would a multiprocessing implementation resemble this?

Answer (score -1):

If you just want an empty queue, and don't care about garbage collection of the older queue, simply instantiate a new queue using the same handle. For example,

```py
    q = Queue(maxsize=max_size)
    q.put(1)
    q.put(2)
    q.put(3)
    q.put(4)
```

Now in order to make this queue empty, you can simply write the following.

```py
    q = Queue(maxsize=max_size)
```

And at this point you should have an empty queue.

Comment: I am not sure if this is thread safe.