# Python: clear items from PriorityQueue

Tags: python, python-2.7, priority-queue

[Clear all items from the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517953/clear-all-items-from-the-queue)

I read the above answer

Im using python 2.7

```
import Queue
pq = Queue.PriorityQueue()
pq.clear()
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: PriorityQueue instance has no attribute 'clear'
```

Is there way to easily empty priority queue instead of manually popping out all items? or would re-instantiating work (i.e. it wouldn't mess with join())?

Comment: The linked answer suggests to use `pg.queue.clear()`.

Comment: pq.queue.clear()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'clear'

Comment: @Evert still error

Comment: `.queue` is undocumented for `Queue()`, so I suspect it's a bit of a hack, and (obviously) can't be relied upon. See Kristof's answer.

Comment: Are you sure you need to be using the `Queue` module? It's not a general purpose data structure, but specifically for synchronized communication between threads. If you don't need the synchronization and just want a generic LIFO queue, use a `collections.deque`. For an unsynchronized priority queue, use a `list` and the functions in the `heapq` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually `pq.queue.clear()`. However, as mentioned in the answers to the question you referenced, this is not documented and potentially unsafe.

The cleanest way is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18873213/3165737):

```
while not q.empty():
    try:
        q.get(False)
    except Empty:
        continue
    q.task_done()
```

Re-instantiating the queue would work too of course (the object would simple be removed from memory), as long as no other part of your code holds on to a reference to the old queue.