# Proper way to clear an asyncio queue in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Errors in my producer/consumer coroutines may leave items and unfinished tasks in the asyncio queue. If an error is encountered, I want to simply stop the loop, cancel the pending tasks and clear the queue. While I can finish the first two things, I cannot find an easy way to clear the queue. After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18873213/2923419), I come up with three methods:

```
import asyncio

q=asyncio.Queue()
for i in range(5):
    q.put_nowait(i)
q.get_nowait()

loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()

#this will raise an error if q cannot join
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait_for(q.join(),1))

#method 1
q._queue.clear()
q._finished.set()
q._unfinished_tasks = 0

#method 2
for _ in range(q.qsize()):
    q.get_nowait()
for _ in range(q._unfinished_tasks):
    q.task_done()

#method 3
del q
q=asyncio.Queue()
```

So which one is better?

Answer (score 7):

Avoid using the "private" methods. From the documentation of [`Queue.task_done`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-queue.html#asyncio.Queue.task_done):

> For each get() used to fetch a task, a subsequent call to task_done() tells the queue that the processing on the task is complete.

```py
def empty_queue(q: asyncio.Queue):
  while not q.empty():
    # Depending on your program, you may want to
    # catch QueueEmpty
    q.get_nowait()
    q.task_done()
```

Answer (score -4):

I did this in various [DBussy example scripts](https://github.com/ldo/dbussy_examples):

```
for task in asyncio.Task.all_tasks(loop) :
    task.cancel()
    try :
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
    except asyncio.CancelledError :
        pass
    #end try
#end for
```

Comment: the question was about `asyncio.Queue`